# What is the best practice to store hidden values in web apps, without using the classic html form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, hidden-field

I hope that this question is not useless ! but  seriously , it is a problem for me .

when I want to build a user interface in a web application to (add, delete ,edit ) something I use HTML forms + `hidden inputs` to store `some values such as "user id"` to be deleted,edited ..

I want to build the same interface using just " `anchors + span + div` " insteand of "`hidden inputs`" . when I write the javascript code that handles "onAdd ,onDelete and onEdit" events I need to know what will be deleted ? `what is the id that will be kicked out from my database` ?

**The question is , how to store this ID in my html tags without using hidden inputs ?**

what I'm using is something like this :

```
<div id="userid_133421" >
    <span>Name</span>
    <a id="onDelete">Delete</a>
    <a id="onEdit">Edit</a>
</div>

$("#onDelete").click(function({

        user_id = $(this).parent().attr('id').substring($(this).attr('id').indexOf('_')+1);

        $.post('index.php?component=user&action=remove&user_id=' + user_id, function(data){

        });
    }));
```

I checked some websites such as [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) , and I found that they don't use this technique to store values (such as file id) , and even more they don't use classic hidden inputs to do that!

I just want to know how do you manage your code to choose the best way ?  :(

Comment: The example you show looks nice. Is something wrong with it?

Comment: @Pekka: It's work , but I think the code is not clean enough ? and contians "deep searching" and "string manip" for something primitive ?

Comment: mmm, yeah, fair point. On the other hand, it's easy to debug and see the ID in question, that's a plus in my book. If you use HTML 5, you could put the ID into a `data-id="12345"` property... Side note, IDs must be unique so giving the delete and edit buttons IDs is probably out of the question (you could use classes instead)

Comment: @Pekka +1 for HTML5 data-id. regarding to the uniqueness , It's just a dummy example :-) , thanks .

Comment: Even if you are posting data using ajax I still recommend to use classic forms, because jQuery has well developed form handling methods. You don't need to construct this complicated URL in `$.post` by hands, for instance you can use `serialize()`. And even if you don't want to use HTML forms, you can still use hidden inputs, because then the code will be better understandable for others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using JQuery, why not use the [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) function to store information?

Answer (score 2):

I second @nfecher! That's how I am doing it right now in an application that I'm working on! We store the ids in the data-myAppName-itemTypeId. The myAppName is creating a pseudo namespace to avoid collisions with other plugins that may use the same data-* attributes: e.g. data-stackoverflow-commentId="4" No need for hidden inputs at all!! You can follow the same style for all elements. If it's a generic delete functionality, you could look up the parent class name and decided which data-* attribute you want to fetch!